# URL not found after ng build

Tags: angular, typescript

I have login route which is working fine on local host but after ng build when comes on login route it show error 404 path not found can you explain am i doing mistake in setting basehref or running build
[image]

Comment: Be careful of disclosing your bookmarks when taking browser screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

After build your project you have to config the server to handle angular routing, for that you need to read this link first [Angular - Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

For Example in Apache server, we need to add this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

> This configs help you when user refresh the page, and you don't lose the routing